# JS - how to append child into an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

For example,

This is my object creation

```
var myObj = {};
```

If I want to add value in my object, i'm doing this way.

```
myObj.name = 'User1';
myObj.role = 'CEO';
```

This is fine. For my `node.js` project scenario, I need to pass `level.type` string object into `myObj`.

In clearly like this,

```
myObj.level.type = 'Level 1';
```

How to I append `level.type` named object values into `myObj`?

I don't think this is may confused you. I need my object values like this,

```
 {
  "name": "User1",
  "role": "CEO",
  "level.type": "Level 1"
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When appending a subproperty, you just need to check if it's already set and if it isn't, do it .

```
myObj.level = myObj.level || {};
myObj.level.type = 'Level 1';
```

That will prevent resetting myObj.level if it's already set.

**Edit**

If you need to pass a property name which has a dot in it, you must quote it and use bracket notation

```
myObj['level.type'] = 'Level 1';
```

same goes for any property name that has special characters in it (- + etc). Key names are stored as strings internally so as long as they are quoted you don't need to fear implicit evaluations.

Comment: Sorry to mislead of my question. I correct it now. See my updated question now

Comment: Superb... Now I got it.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 5):

The child object has to be created first:

```
myObj.level = {};
myObj.level.type = 'Level 1';
```

Or shorter:

```
myObj.level = {type: 'Level 1'};
```

or indeed if there is a chance `level` was already a child of `myObj`:

```
myObj.level = myObj.level || {type: 'Level 1'};
```

In sum you can create `myObj` like this:

```
var myObj = {
 name: 'User1',
 role: 'CEO',
 level: {type: 'Level 1'}
};
```

And to address your 'misleading':

```
var myObj = {
 name: 'User1',
 role: 'CEO',
 'level.type': 'Level 1'
};
```

Comment: that could reset the myObj.level value if it was set elsewhere. You know, copying part of the code, pasting elsewhere, then coming back to SO wondering what might be wrong...

Comment: Sorry to mislead of my question. I correct it now. See my updated question now.

Answer (score 0):

myObj.level is undefined at first
you need to init myObj.level as an object:

myObj.level = {type: 'Level 1'}